# stop code outside useeffect from keep running

Tags: reactjs

I bulit a timmer with useEffect and setInterval but this useEffect keep running the code that is out from useEffect and i don't want that

```
    const [seconds,setSeconds] = useState(0)
    const [minutes,setMinutes] = useState(15)

    const { orderId } = useParams()

   useEffect(()=>{
        const interval = setInterval(() => {

            if (seconds > 0) {
                setSeconds(seconds => seconds - 1)
            }
            if (seconds === 0) {
                if (minutes === 0) {
                    return () => clearInterval(interval)
                } else {
                    setMinutes(minutes => minutes - 1)
                    setSeconds(59)
                }
            } 
        }, 1000)

        return () => clearInterval(interval);

    },[seconds,minutes])

   useEffect(()=>{
        if(minutes === 0 && seconds === 1 ){
            //alert('hello guys ')
        }

    },[seconds,minutes])

    console.log(orderId) //this console keep running every 1 second  
                           even though it out from the useEffect
```

I don't want the code outside the useEffect to keep running

Comment: `setSeconds(seconds => seconds - 1)` You're setting state every second, which is going to cause a rerender, hence the log. If you don't want to render, what do you want to do? I'm assuming these minutes and seconds get put on the screen, so rerendering seems correct to me.

Comment: i want my timer to keep going but not to run all the code on the page every secound

Comment: What code **do** you want to run ever second? Do you want to update something on the screen? Or run some other code not shown in the question? Or do you want *nothing* to happen every second, and only do something when the time hits 0?

Comment: it's a timer that run in every secound in the useEffect but it's run the console.log that is outside of the useEffect every secound i want it to not run the code that is out side useEffect

Comment: If you don't want to render, then delete the calls to `setSeconds` and `setMinutes`. But you must have put them there for a reason, so i'm trying to find out what you **do** want to do every second. You've made it clear what you do **not** want to do every second.

Comment: It is a 15 minutes timer i want the code to run every second and decrease the second by 1 that why it run every second but the code out side the useEffect run every second too

Comment: `and decrease the second by 1` Do you mean you want to decrease what's shown to the user on the page?

Comment: it show a use a timer that go down from 15 min to 0

Comment: If you want to change what's shown, then the console.log is expected. In order to change what's on the page, you must rerender the component.

Comment: i Edited the code above maybe it will be clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. The purpose of calling a set state function (eg, `setSeconds` or `setMinutes`) is to cause the component to rerender. Your console.log statement is in the body of the component, so it will run every time the component rerenders. And since you're setting state every second, you are rerendering every second.

If you don't want to rerender the component then you could change your code to not set state. But by definition, since you aren't rerendering the component, then you aren't changing the time displayed to the user, so the user cannot tell that a countdown is happening. This could be used if you want to silently wait 15 minutes, and then do something at the end:

```
const ExampleComponent = () => {
  // No need for state, since we won't be showing anything to the user

  useEffect(() => {
    const fifteenMinutes = 900000;
    const id = setTimeout(() => {
      alert('15 minutes have elapsed');
    }, fifteenMinutes), 

    return () => clearTimeout(id);
  }, []);

  // ...
}
```